# How to automate running a google search for multiple strings of content in a google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with a list of terms that I need to run a google search for. What I want to be able to do is automate running these searches so that a new Google Chrome tab is created for each search query.

For example:

[List of Google Search Queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDwpt.png)

Now I want to search the google search engine for each term, like 'Social Media Marketing for Small Business' and have the results open up in a new tab on Chrome.

Then automate another search for the string 'What Is Social Media Marketing' and have it open in a new tab.

And continue doing this for all the terms in my list.

Is this possible? And how?

I tried creating a function app, but wasn't able to get it right.

Comment: I’d consider using textFinder

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

> Solution 1: Using Apps Scripts

**CODE 1:**

```
function openGoogleSearchTabs() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var query = data[i][0];
    var searchURL = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + encodeURI(query);
    var html = "<script>window.open('" + searchURL + "', '_blank');</script>";
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), 'Opening Google Search Tabs');
    Utilities.sleep(1000); // Adjust the sleep time (in milliseconds) as needed to avoid rate limiting issues
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can also produce a dialogue box, showing the links to each search item, like this:

[image]

**CODE 2:**

```
function openGoogleSearchTabs() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  
  var links = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var query = data[i][0];
    var searchURL = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + encodeURI(query);
    links.push("Search " + (i + 1) + ": <a href='" + searchURL + "' target='_blank'>" + query + "</a>");
    Utilities.sleep(1000); // Adjust the sleep time (in milliseconds) as needed to avoid rate limiting issues
  }

  var html = links.join('<br>');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), 'Google Search Links');
}
```

> Solution 2: Using a formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"", HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com/search?q=" & ENCODEURL(A2:A), A2:A), ""))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! :-) I went with option 2 and it produced exactly the results I was looking for. I love how it opens up the dialogue box for easy referencing. :-)